# TinyMCE 5: How can I add image vertical alignment inputs?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

How can I add image vertical alignment select input (top, middle, bottom) to Advanced or new tab?

[look this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGXsV.jpg)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a new field to any of those tabs you will need to modify the source code of the plugin.  I would look at the un-minified version of the source code for the image plugin to see how it adds the fields that are currently on the form and you can mimic that behavior for your new field.

Note that you will also need to look at how the plugin update the attributes of the image tag to make sure you do the same with the value of your custom field.